# Where should I ask a question about meta data in video streams?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to know if it is possible to attach meta data to each frame in a video stream. And what formats are best suited for that, if any.

To me it is programming related, but I can see why Stack Overflow would not be too happy about that question.

Any suggestions of other parts of Stack Exchange that could accept such a question?

Comment: In which way it is programming related? I'd accept questions coming up on StackOverflow related to e.g. to the [tag:ffmpeg] tag, and how to use it for a particular and clearly stated use and test case as acceptable.

Comment: BTW Video meta data usually isn't really put upon _"each frame"_ with most codecs. For e.g. MPEG-TS it's put in special SI tables, that are outcasted at fixed timing periods.

Comment: Ok. I guess I consider it programming related since I intend to produce software based on the answer. So it´s a bit far fetched. 
But I basically need to stream id codes or similar with the frames to sync and merge with other data later on.

Comment: Hmmm, what about http://computergraphics.stackexchange.com for your question?

Answer (score 7):

In general video processing is programming related.

There are several tags on Stack Overflow that address such stuff, like [ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ffmpeg) or [opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv), and you can even ask questions about [video-processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/video-processing).

You have to make it crystal clear, which kind of video stream you are processing, there are many formats and codecs around.

Also, you need to make it crystal clear which kind of metadata you actually need to inject (as mentioned that's usually not done on frame level).

---

Also take care **not to add** any programming language related tags like e.g. [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) or [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), unless giving a concise sample code, of what you have tried, or at least non working pseudo code of what you want to achieve.
The latter option requires you to give an exact explanation, where you are stuck, and what the compile time/runtime errors are verbatim.

---

> To me it is programming related, but I can see why Stack Overflow would not be too happy about that question.

You should probably flesh out your concerns in that question here. I've got a feeling that what you're trying to ask gets *too broad* as mentioned from these policies:

> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: Well, thats why I need to ask a general question. I want to know which options I have. I might be able to select stream format to suit my needs,

Comment: @EinarSundgren You may simply come up _too broad_.

Comment: That's the crux of it. It's marginal in terms of topic but personally I'd accept it here; however, it does need to be _specific_, otherwise you are going to need to find a chat room or _library_, not an SE site!